# Using multiple SQL Statements to get single result query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am looking to create 2 teams. After research, I have found that I can sort my table, then assign a "ranking" system in the new sorted order. Now, I am trying to pull just the odd number rows (and even number after I figure out odd).

This statement will do the sorting and ranking:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS weight FROM golfers t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE trip_name_table_ID = 1 ORDER BY golfer_handicap
```

See [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/987e9f/4) for visual.

So I am creating `weight` after the sorting. Now, I want to pull my data off of that `weight` column with this code I found for pulling Odd row (which should now be pulling odd number of weighted sort):

```
SELECT * FROM golfers WHERE weight IN(SELECT weight FROM golfers WHERE weight%2 <> 0);
```

How do I use both statements off of each other since `weight` is an `AS` column? and what would my
`while($rowid = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {}`
look like?

Comment: The sample fiddle is for MySQL 5.6. Is that the version you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select only the odd numbered rows from your SQL query then you should use `weight%2=1` instead.

The full query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS weight 
    FROM golfers t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
    WHERE trip_name_table_ID = 1 
    ORDER BY golfer_handicap
) as t1 
WHERE weight%2=0
```

I don't know why you are using `while($rowid = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {}` but your mysqli result will contain the exact data that your query returned. You can use `foreach` instead though.

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['golfer_name'];
    echo $row['weight'];
}
```

Comment: You're a savior. Exactly what I was looking for. I was able to tweak some things to make it how I needed, but thank you very much!! I am still very very new to SQL and I dont even fully understand the `SELECT` statement with `t.*` and everything, but this is what I needed! Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeDietrich If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: I am following a set of Youtube videos, and I believe the next video introduces PDO to "streghten our security". I'm learning, applying and creating, all at the same time. haha. Thanks!

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with security. Both PDO and mysqli offer parameter binding which you should already be using, but PDO is a much simpler extension.